# Where is Qt located after installation in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, qt

ubuntu 20.04 TLS

I need to install the Qt libraries and follow this path: *"PATH_TO_QT/QT_VERSION/QT_ARCH/lib/cmake"* (for example */home/user/Qt/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/cmake or Users/edouard/Qt/5.7/clang_64/lib/cmake*)

I'm installing Qt:

`sudo apt update
 sudo apt install qt5-default`

After I do:

`whereis qt5
qt5: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5 /usr/lib/qt5 /usr/share/qt5`

but there is no *lib/cmake* folder in these directories:

`cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5
ls
bin  mkspecs  plugins  qt.conf`

`cd /usr/lib/qt5
ls
bin`

`cd /usr/lib/qt5
ls
bin`

Comment: @MarkPlotnick yes, is this the equivalent of _qt/lib/cmake?_

Comment: I will need to check the contents of that directory. May take a day or so.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick no longer necessary, the directory you specified can be used as `qt/lib/cmake`